# grab record by inherant table sequence index

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm kind of new to Progress and finding it really hard to look up some existing solutions to problems, since the keywords are so ambiguous.

I digress, is there a way to access a record in a table by it's sequence index inside of the table, without having to create a field and manually track it?

Thanks

Comment: You can get the downloadable KB here: download.progress.com/open/products/prokb/ProKBsetup.exe

Comment: It may be possible [in 11.2](http://blog.consultingwerk.de/consultingwerkblog/2012/09/whats-coming-in-the-next-openedge-releases/) using the SQL engine if they implement the `OFFSET` keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not a direct answer to your question,

1) each table has a ROWID and RECID value which can be used to find it directly without adding a new field. It's value can change over the course of time, so it's best to only use it for a single session. So once you know which record is of interest, your program can go directly back to that record w/out having to do a potentially slow search.

2) Progress also added the "table-scan" phrase, which returns the records in db order. I forget which version it was added though, so it may or may not be usable on your platform.

3) Another possible approach would be to create a TT and populate that with links to the main DB, and then sort it in the order you want.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to use RECID/ROWID as an "inherent order"... they aren't in any particular order.  They go in the first hole that they fit in.  In an ideal case where all records are all the same size, they never change size, only one session is ever writing and they never get deleted then maybe they would be in RECID order.  But I'm pretty sure that all real systems break several of those conditions.

Comment: From what I can infer from the original question, the OP wants to find a particular record w/out regard to it'd data, or having to add another field to it. RECID/ROWID provides that functionality.

If he wants a record at an index by an arbitrary sort order, then that gets into the query BY phrase, followed by getting the number of records until the code gets to the position it needs.

Comment: "Sequence" means order.  He talks about otherwise needing to add a field to obtain the desired result - so there is clearly a desired (but unspecified) ordering.  Maybe the desire is for a simple integer, maybe a time stamp maybe something else.  My point in my comment is that RECIDs are not ordered, it is a common mistake to think that they are.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such capability.  You need to create a field that captures whatever attributes you feel makes up an inherent order.